# How to bind 3 comboboxes POWERSHELL and WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, powershell, combobox

Here is my problem: I have 3 `ComboBox`es that read data from an mdb file.

Selected value from the first one will affect on what shows in the second one, and selected value from the second one will affect on what shows in the third one. Result from the third one will populate in a `TextBox`.

[image: example]

Here is the code I use to load the data:

```
function GetData() {

    $objOleDbConnection1= New-Object "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection"
    $objOleDbCommand = New-Object "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand"
    $objOleDbAdapter = New-Object "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter"
    $objDataTable = New-Object "System.Data.DataTable"

    $objOleDbConnection1.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Script\test_1.mdb;"
    $objOleDbConnection1.Open()
    $objOleDbCommand.Connection = $objOleDbConnection1
    $objOleDbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT SORT + ' ' + '-' + ' ' + Tekst, SAPstruktur FROM SAPstruktur where SAPstruktur like 'A__' ORDER BY ID ASC"

    #set the Adapter object
    $objOleDbAdapter.SelectCommand = $objOleDbCommand

    #fill the objDataTable object with the results
    $objOleDbAdapter.Fill($objDataTable)
    return $objDataTable.DefaultView
    $objOleDbConnection1.Close()
}
```

And here is my XAML code for combo box #1:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="mdb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="275" Grid.Column="1"  DisplayMemberPath="Expr1000" SelectedValuePath="SAPstruktur" ItemsSource="{Binding PsList[GetData]}" SelectedIndex="0"/>
```

**Question:** how to connect all these 3 combo boxes? I managed to populate all three combo boxes (calling function GetData, GetData1 etc.) but i have no clue how to connect them together.

I work with WPF dialog window (XAML) + PowerShell file so i guess that action happens in ps1 that sends results to XAML.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by connecting the comboboxes. Could you describe what you're trying to achieve by "connecting" them?

Comment: That could help : `$combo1.Add_DropDownClosed({ #populate $combo2 })`, `$combo2.Add_DropDownClosed({ #populate $combo3 })` **@Mathias R Jessen** see the picture

Comment: Thanks for responce. By connecting i meant to bind them in a way that if i choose a value from the first one this choice will affect list values in the second one, chosen value from the secong one will affect list of value in the third one... @sodawillow: do i need to bind any variables to WPF?? Where shall i put this code? Inside the function??

Comment: @sodawillow : do i need to bind any variables to WPF?? Where shall i put this code? Inside the function?? Remember that combobox is not inside powershell script. It is located inside xaml file, so there is need to be some binding between powershell script variable and WPF (xaml).

Comment: You can read this to learn how to do : http://learn-powershell.net/2014/08/01/powershell-and-wpf-checkboxes/ (edited)

Comment: Thanks, but biggest challenge for me is not doing all this in powershell but to combine this with wpf( har to find any website explaining this).
I will check this link out.

Comment: I have added an example

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very simple working example.

When an item is selected in `ComboBox1`, `ComboBox2` is emptied and filled with appropriate values.

```cs
#XAML for GUI
[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="Window" Title="Initial Window" WindowStartupLocation = "CenterScreen"
    SizeToContent = "WidthAndHeight" ShowInTaskbar = "True" Background = "lightgray"> 
    <StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox1">
        <ComboBoxItem>France</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>USA</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
    <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox2">
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
"@

#load XAML
$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)

#bind WPF elements to PS variables
$ComboBox1 = $Window.FindName("ComboBox1")
$ComboBox2 = $Window.FindName("ComboBox2")

#event: when ComboBox1 is closed
$ComboBox1.Add_DropDownClosed({

    #empty ComboBox2   
    $ComboBox2.Items.Clear()

    #depending on ComboBox1 value
    switch($ComboBox1.Text) {

        "France" {
            #add items  to ComboBox2
            $ComboBox2.Items.Add("Paris")
            $ComboBox2.Items.Add("Lyon")
        }

        "USA" {
            #add items to ComboBox2
            $ComboBox2.Items.Add("New-York")
            $ComboBox2.Items.Add("Chicago")            }
    }
})

#show window
$Window.Showdialog() | Out-Null
```

Based on what I read here : http://learn-powershell.net/2014/08/01/powershell-and-wpf-checkboxes/

Comment: Should that be $ComboBox1.Add_DropDownClosed() or $ComboBox1.Add_SelectionChanged() or something else entirely?